# Подрезка строки с конца на указанное количество символов в C#

Tags: c#, wpf, строки

Существует ли какая-либо функция для этой задачи, или же придется делать вручную?
Код работает не правильно!

```
string version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().‌​Version.ToString().S‌​ubstring(System.Refl‌​ection.Assembly.GetE‌​xecutingAssembly().G‌​etName().Version.ToS‌​tring().Length - 2);
```

Comment: `substring` не подходит для ваших нужд?

Comment: @maxwell ну вообще можно и через него, но в таком случае мне придется получать длину строки, что в частных случаях чрезмерно увеличивает длину кода.

Comment: Можешь написать свой метод расширения, это же мощный C#.

Comment: @Alex78191 ну, это очевидно, но имеет ли смысл писать что-то если это что-то уже существует?

Comment: Вот именно, что не существует.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из комментариев видно, что вы пытаетесь получить последнее число версии приложения - `Revision` (ревизию). Ваш подход с вырезанием строк неверен (а что если это число будет трехзначное? четырехзначное?).

Дело в том, что версия приложения - это экземпляр класса [`Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.version.aspx).
Просто воспользуйтесь свойством этого класса:

```
var ver = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
Console.WriteLine(ver.Revision);
```

PS. Обратите внимание, если вам потребуется где-то выводить номер версии приложения, можно воспользоваться удобной перегруженной версией метода [`ToString(int fieldCount)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bff8h2e1.aspx), например версия без ревизии: `.ToString(3);`

Comment: ну вообще я пытался получить версию без ревизии (трёхзначное число), но так как ревизия у меня всегда равно нулю, я просто сделал так:
string fullversion = "1.2.3.0";
string version = fullversion.Replace(".0", "");
Коротко, и выполняет свою задачу.

Comment: Без ревизии: `ToString(3)`

Comment: Прочитайте что написано в PS.

Comment: А если версия "1.0.5.0", то ваш реплейс сработает совсем не так как нужно

Answer (score 2):

Вам в помощь [SubString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string value = "This is a string.";
string substring = value.Substring(0, value.Length - 4);
//на вывод ->This is a str
```

Перепишите ваш код вот так и почитайте о `SubString` по ссилке что бы не ошибаться

```
string version=System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString().Substring(0,System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString().Length-2);
```

Comment: Это простейший метод. Но что в случае, если я не хочу выделять память под строку? У меня получится вот это:
string version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString().Substring(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString().Length - 2);
P.S: Как код поместить в должный для этого блок?

Comment: что это за код такой?и вы хотите что это работало?

Comment: @SNMetamorph В комментариях не особо красиво смотрится (комментарии не предназначены для кода более чем одна строка), но если очень хочется -- заключите код в апострофы. И, комментарии можно править в течение 5 минут, уже поздно.

Comment: @Vardan Vardanyan получает строку с версией сборки и исключает два последних символа из этой строки

Comment: а ты точно уверен что написанный тобой код это делает?я вот сомневаюсь,определитесь что вам надо на самом деле

Comment: @VardanVardanyan лол, нашел ошибку, ну вообщем первый аргумент метода Substring должен быть 0, а второй - то что у меня в коде.

Comment: и да советую использовать переменные в коде что бы получить более читабельный код и избегать таких ошибок

Comment: @AK не просто апострофы, а обратные апострофы.